# Grafana Dashboard Time Series delta

Tags: sql, grafana, dashboard

I am plotting a metric on a time series panel inside a Grafana dashboard. How can I make the time series show the delta for the chosen timeframe - the difference between the first and last value in the dashboard interval, starting from 0?

I did not find anything helpful in the "Transform" tab or the "Visual mapping" part inside the panel settings.

Comment: It's better to do with SQL, not Grafana's Transformations. Subtract all values a value of your metric at the beginning of your time range (`$__from`).

Answer (score 0):

Using transformations (for instance if you are using a data source that does not support SQL) you can do that in a two-step process.

First, you need to compute the min and max values. To do so use the Reduce transformation and type the calculations "Max" and "Min".
This will include two columns Min and Max.

Now, you need to use the "Add field from calculation" transformation, select Mode: Binary operation, and in operation choose "Max" "-" "Min".

I don't know the specifics of your data, but that should do it